# Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "www.google.com" google_currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I've been using the google_currency gem with great success but now I've started gettinggetting a Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "www.google.com".

I can't think of any changes made that would cause this. Does anyone have any ideas as to what this could be? I have tried updating to the latest gem version but to no effect. I also tried telnet google.com 80 from my development environment and it connected without issue.

Full trace:

```
    rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "www.google.com" port 80                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'                                                                                                                                           
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'                                                                                                                                     
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'                                                                                                                                              
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'   
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:313:in `open_http'                                                                                                                                            
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:724:in `buffer_open'                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `block in open_loop'                                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `catch'                                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:208:in `open_loop'                                                                                                                                            
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'                                                                                                                                             
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:704:in `open'                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:712:in `read'                                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/google_currency-3.2.0/lib/money/bank/google_currency.rb:128:in `fetch_rate'                                                                                                                       
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/google_currency-3.2.0/lib/money/bank/google_currency.rb:99:in `block in get_rate'                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/google_currency-3.2.0/lib/money/bank/google_currency.rb:98:in `synchronize'                                                                                                                       
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/google_currency-3.2.0/lib/money/bank/google_currency.rb:98:in `get_rate'                                                                                                                          
/home/action/workspace/x/lib/tasks/import_newstyle.rake:22:in `block in <top (required)>'                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:209:in `in_namespace'                                                                                                                                        
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:146:in `namespace'                                                                                                                                         
/home/action/workspace/x/lib/tasks/import_newstyle.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                            
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'                                                                                                                              
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'                                                                                                                     
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'                                                                                                                              
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'                                                                                                                             
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `each'                                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:654:in `run_tasks_blocks'                                                                                                                                      
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:362:in `run_tasks_blocks'                                                                                                                                 
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:449:in `load_tasks'                                                                                                                                            
/home/action/workspace/x/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'                                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'                                                                                                                                         
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'                                                                                                                                    
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'                                                                                                                                
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'                                                                                                                                         
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'                                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'                                                                                                                          
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'                                                                                                                                                   
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                     
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'                                                                                                                                                                                  
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Having the same issue, how did you solve it ?

Comment: I am also having the same issue how did you guys solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a server, what helped me was to restarting the server I hope that will help someone. I am not sure what coursed the problem because I am working on a FreeBSD server. Restarting the server is what helped me.